# See if *external* software list is up-to-date

Tags: windows, database, monitoring, version-control

There exist many programs that check wether the programs installed on your computer are up to date (and possibly allow you to update them automatically), i.e. Filehippo update checker, SUMO etc.

I have however yet to find a software that takes an *externally generated* program *list* as input and outputs which of these programs in the list are (not) up-to-date.

---

**In short:** I am looking for a program/tool that, instead of checking if all *installed* programs are up to date, accepts an *external* program list as input and which either

- Outputs the latest version-number available for the program, or
- Also accepts the current version-number of each program in the list as input, and outputs wether that version of the program is up-to-date.

---

Any suggestion is much appreciated. I could also try to write a script myself if a program for example has a public API to access its database. Thanks!

Comment: https://chocolatey.org, and create your own package perhaps

Comment: Chocolatey seemed like an interesting option on first sight, but it looks like it still needs to run on the machine itself that has all the software installed. How would Chocolatey be used to take an external list of programs as input?

Comment: @AdFundum You could call the Choco API to retrieve version numbers of Choco packages. Note that these often, but don't need to coincide with the actual software's version number (e.g.because of [package fix notation](https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/wiki/CreatePackages#package-fix-version-notation)).

Comment: I can dig that, but then again, you can only do that on Choco packages? I would have a, for example, textbased list stating 'Winrar' 'Java' 'Google Chrome' and I would have to look up the latest version of them.

Can Chocolatey take such textbased-name as input, find the corresponding package and return the latest versionnumber?

Comment: @AdFundum Indeed, you are limited to software products for which corresponding packages exist. I suppose you can search through the packages if you don't know the exact name, in the same way it's done on https://chocolatey.org/packages. Retrieving the latest version numbers is definitely possible, this is what `choco upgrade all` does under the hood. You might ask the core devs whether there is any API documentation (couldn't find any right now): https://gitter.im/chocolatey/choco

Comment: I'll see what I can find. Thanks for the suggestions and help!

Comment: I just realized, I really hope you were asking about windows...

Comment: I was indeed. I added the tag to the question for future reference, thanks.